# Fetching arraylist from JSON Object using jquery,ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am getting a response from my server in the form of a JSON object which has the attributes `id`, `description` and one `arraylist`. How can I retrieve this  `arraylist` from the returned object using jQuery or AJAX?

Comment: can you provide an example of json you want to work on?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `json` you receive looks like this:

```
{
  id: 1,
  description: "sample json",
  arrayList: ["list", "of", "sample", "elements"]
}
```

you can use an `ajax` like below to make a call to your api and on `success` you will get back the `data`, all you need to do is use the unique key of the *arrayList* to get the corresponding array and return it in a callback.

```
function getArrayList(url, response) {

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
     response(data.arrayList);
    },
    error: function(request, error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });

}

getArraList(some_url, arrayList => console.log(arrayList))
```